# How can I clean hydrogen peroxide stains?

Tags: cleaning

I had a mixture of hydrogen peroxide and White vinegar in a cup. It fell on the floor and now there are stains (1 ft * 1 ft). How do I clean the stains?

Comment: What material is the floor constructed from? That mixture is more akin to a bleaching agent, than a stain.  As such, your job will be to put the color *back in*.

Comment: If you've spilled it on a carpet, you'll likely have to "clean" the rest of the carpet. As this spot is now the "cleanest" spot on the carpet.